# How to override lodash snakeCase functionality

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I'm using lodash to convert text to snakeCase and I am stuck in a specific scenario where I should retain alphanumeric value as it is.

When I pass string as "This is AAA456B". lodash `snakeCase(str)` is converting it as "this_is_aaa_456_b"

The expected result is like "this_is_aaa456b".

Is there a way I can override the lodash `snakeCase(str)` to ignore the alphanumeric value?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "override the lodash function". If you mean whether there is an argument you can pass for it, there isn't, according to the documentation. However, have you thought about creating your own function for it instead?

Answer (score 3):

You should create your own function, rather than overriding the existing

```js
const str = "This is AAA456B"

_.mixin({
  customSnakeCase: s => _
    .chain(s)
    .split(/(\d+)/)
    .map(_.snakeCase)
    .join('')
    .value()
})



console.log(_.customSnakeCase(str))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```